# Codename One - Eclipse Plugin

Tags: codenameone

I get the following install error for the codename one eclips plugin.

[image: Plugin install error]

[image: Detail]

Any suggestions on how to resolve this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a version of Eclipse for Java developers. It seems the Java editor functionality isn't available in your copy of eclipse.

I recommend using a recent version of JDK 1.8 and a Eclipse Neon 2 or newer (e.g. Oxygen etc.).